# Can I claim points for before deemed date in Expressions of Interest (EOIs) for Australian state?

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, australia

I am looking to lodge EOIs for Australia immigration under subclasses 189, 190 & 491.
I have a bachelor and a master degree in non-computer field but I work as a software developer for over 6 years now.
I have received this skills assessment from ACS deducting around 4 years from the total experience.
[image: ACS outcome]

While lodging the EOI, it asks whether *"Is this employment related to the nominated occupation?"* to which I have chosen **Yes** but I am not completely sure whether it should be *Yes* or *No*.
[image: EOI question]

Please suggest

[Here is a youtube immigration related channel that explains my confusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18OxqRb1Rok&ab_channel=AustralianImmigrationLawServices) Timestamp 03:17

Comment: The video link is broken.

Comment: @jcm Updated the link

Comment: The title seems different from the question in the body. Does ticking 'Yes' mean you claim points on these roles?

Comment: yes. you basically say that yes this is experience towards counting points for overall score.

Comment: In that case I think you should ask a registered migration agent.